# Merge Last Column Cell Dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script

i would like to merge two cells dynamically. the script that i make add two columns to the right. 
(example:The last column is M..after i run the script, coloumns N & O are created.

i would like to merge row 4 for column N & O automatically.

this is the code i have so far

```
function tambahcolumn() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lastcol = ss.getLastColumn()

ss.insertColumnsAfter(lastcol, 2)
ss.setColumnWidth((lastcol+1), 190);
ss.setColumnWidth((lastcol+2), 390);
//ss.getRange(4,lastcol+1:4,lastcol+2).merge();
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overloaded getRange construct getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) needs to be used, in your case

```
ss.getRange(4, lastcol+1, 1, 2).merge();
```